# maven-assembly-plugin prepending to classpath

Tags: java, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a module and I am using maven-assembly-plugin to create an executable jar with dependencies. When I run install, the plugin prepends the name of the project ("vicinity") before the jar name and all the jar contents, i.e.:

```
$ jar -tvf vicinity-confirm-assets.jar | more
     0 Tue Jan 20 17:18:10 EST 2015 META-INF/
   213 Tue Jan 20 17:18:08 EST 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Tue Jan 20 17:18:10 EST 2015 vicinity/
     0 Thu Nov 13 20:52:16 EST 2014 vicinity/META-INF/
   134 Thu Nov 13 20:52:14 EST 2014 vicinity/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Thu Nov 13 20:52:06 EST 2014 vicinity/org/
     0 Thu Nov 13 20:52:10 EST 2014 vicinity/org/boon/
     0 Thu Nov 13 20:52:10 EST 2014 vicinity/org/boon/cache/
     0 Thu Nov 13 20:52:10 EST 2014 vicinity/org/boon/collections/
     0 Thu Nov 13 20:52:10 EST 2014 vicinity/org/boon/concurrent/
    ...
     0 Tue Jan 20 17:17:50 EST 2015 vicinity/META-INF/maven/com.thingy.webapp/confirmassets/
  2208 Tue Jan 20 17:17:44 EST 2015 vicinity/META-INF/maven/com.thingy.webapp/confirmassets/pom.xml
   127 Tue Jan 20 16:25:22 EST 2015 vicinity/META-INF/maven/com.thingy.webapp/confirmassets/pom.properties
```

Here is the plugin xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.thingy.webapp.confirmassets.ToolbarResourcesUrlTester</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/resources/dist.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and here is the dist.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<assembly>
    <id>confirm-assets</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <unpackOptions>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/LICENSE*</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/README*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </unpackOptions>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/resources/META-INF/services</directory>
            <outputDirectory>META-INF/services</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>    
</assembly>
```

ETA: The "vicinity" prepend is coming from the parent pom's `<build><finalName>vicinity</finalName>...</build>`. But it makes no sense to prepend this to every file and dependency included in the jar. I tried overriding with an empty `<finalName></finalName>` tag in my module's pom, but then I get a dash prepended. How do I get rid of this altogether and just include the correctly named contents in the jar?

ALSO: The problem I am having is that when I try to run my main class from the command line, I get:

```
 $ java -jar vicinity-confirm-assets.jar 
Error: Could not find or load main class com.thingy.webapp.confirmassets.ToolbarResourcesUrlTester
```

Also, there are two MANIFEST.MF files.

```
$ jar -tvf vicinity-confirm-assets.jar | grep MANI
   213 Tue Jan 20 18:07:26 EST 2015 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
   134 Thu Nov 13 20:52:14 EST 2014 vicinity/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

The first one:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: barclaydunn
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_65
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.1.1
Main-Class: com.thingy.webapp.confirmassets.ToolbarResourcesUrlTest
 er
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

The second:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: slandelle
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_65
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.2
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

I am guessing there are two because of, and the prepending comes from, the fact that this is a child module. The second is from the parent pom, I am guessing.

Am I trying to do something that can't / shouldn't be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else has this problem, I found that you can control whether the base directory is included with `<includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>` in the dist.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<assembly>
    <id>confirm-assets</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>

    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    ...
```

For more info, see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/advanced-descriptor-topics.html#Using_an_Alternative_Assembly_Base_Directory